# How could the NODE_ENV check cause the hot loading to be a page refreshing?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

Recently I have a project setup for Hot module reloading, 
I use this script to start dev via webpack-dev-server:
 
`"NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --config webpack.dev.js"`

The hot module reloading works. Until I change

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
        renderWrapper(App);
    });
}
```

**to**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    // Original HMR code
}
```

Then every time I change something, it became a full page reloading.
I found the following log in the console of Chrome:

> [HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload! 
>   [HMR] Error: Aborted because
>   ./client/containers/SearchBox.jsx is not accepted 
>   Update propagation:
>   ./client/containers/SearchBox.jsx
>  -> ./client/components/HomePage.jsx
>   
> -> ./client/components/App/index.jsx
>  -> ./client/index.jsx

**Why?**

If I don't do that `development` check, everything works.

Furthermore, do I need to check that for doing HMR? If I create the production build without taking out the HMR block, will it cause a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` right before your condition you will probably get `undefined`. That is why your app can't catch module updates.

The thing is that you set `NODE_ENV=development` for `nodejs`'s environment, but not for `webpack`'s. In your `webpack.config.js` add the following plugin to plugins list:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  process: {
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
  }
})
```

This will tell `webpack` to replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your client code to the appropriate value. Don't forget to wrap it in `JSON.stringify` as in example above. See this [doc link](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) for details.